# Get specific event count, Google Analytics 4 in Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

How can I get a specific event count
ex. eventName "video_start" and "Form"

I get total event count with "metrics":[{"name":"eventCount"}], but want only two events

POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport
BODY JSON:

```
{
"entity":{"propertyId":"IDIDID"},
"metrics":[{"name":"sessions"}],
"metrics":[{"name":"conversions"}],
"metrics":[{"name":"eventCount"}],
"dimensions":[{"name":"sessionDefaultChannelGrouping"}],
"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2021-01-01","endDate":"today"}]
}
```

DOC: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

Comment: and if possible, spesifc "conversions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get a report on two events, you'll need to add a dimension filter for the specific events [reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#dimension_filters).

```
  "dimensionFilter": {
    "filter": {
      "fieldName": "eventName",
      "inListFilter": {
        "values": [
          "video_start",
          "Form"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: OK, thanks. that will sum up the event Count for all the events listed in th filter, possible to get each event (set in the filter) separately i samme respons?

Comment: and if I use dimensionFilter you dont get the totalsForAllResults ex. sessions? Possible to also get totalts for all counts in addtion to sessionDefaultChannelGrouping and eventname filter?

Comment: You can include `eventName` as visible dimension in the request to get the count of each event in the filter. So, update from `"dimensions":[{"name":"sessionDefaultChannelGrouping"}],` to `"dimensions":[{"name":"sessionDefaultChannelGrouping"},{"name":"eventName"}],`.

Comment: You can include `"metricAggregations": [ "TOTAL" ]` in the request to get totals. Totals are calculated on the filtered report data. In this case, the total is the `eventCount` total for the two events. There is not a way to get the total for all events in a report that filters on `eventName`. Please send two API requests (One with the filter, one without the fiilter) for that use case.

Comment: hi thanks. is it also possible to list EVENT PARAMETER key and value in the api? i have a event called "search", want to list all internal search values on my site through the apii. event parameter key is "search" and the serach term is given under event parameter value: eks. "jacket"

Comment: You'll need to register the event parameters as a custom definition. This is the general [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#custom_dimensions). Once registered, you can query for each event parameter key. This is an [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/advanced#event-scoped_custom_dimensions). In your example, a request will contain `customEvent:search` (this is the parameter name and not the event name) as a dimension name, and the response will contain `jacket`.